# Edit specific element in JavaScript 2D array and not the column

Tags: javascript, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array

When manually creating a 2D array and editing a specific element I get the desired results. If I create it with a for loop and edit one element in the array, it changes the whole array in each row, in turn editing the whole column.

Is there a better way to create 2D arrays with a for loop to avoid this behavior?

```
var grid = [1,2,3];
var gridRows = ["O","O","O"];

for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
        grid[i] = gridRows;
    }
}
```

[Image of the for loops output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OEFd.png)

```
//--------------------
//The manually created 2D Array
manualGrid = [["O","O","O"],["O","O","O"],["O","O","O"]];
```

[Image of the manual methods output in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQrWL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are objects in javascript which are passed by reference . To avoid this just change your code to :

```
var grid = [1,2,3];
var gridRows = ["O","O","O"];

for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
        grid[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(gridRows));
    }
}
```